# Create a new array from multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays

My title is probably not doing a good job describing what I'm trying to do, but essentially, I'm want to combine multiple rows into an array (or something similar) into a new column.

I really just need what is in the multiple rows to exist in a single row, specific to each id.

My data lists users and each row is a new purchase (example below):

| id | purchase history |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 1 | banana |
| 1 | blueberry |
| 2 | banana |
| 2 | apple |

I want to create the "path" of purchases so the output looks like this:

| id | purchase path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple, banana, blueberry |
| 2 | banana, apple |

or even like this is fine:

| id | purchase1 | purchase2 | purchase3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | banana | blueberry |
| 2 | banana | apple | NULL |

I've tried a bunch of random things (different array functions, pivot) but have gotten no where close. Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous posts, it looks as if you use Teradata. If that's so, `XMLAGG` might help.

```
select id, 
  trim(trailing ',' from (xmlagg(purchase_history || ',' order by purchase_history) (varchar(500))))
from purchase
group by id;
```